# In a Custom RegularExpressionAttribute, Constructor is not calling after first time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, localization, custom-attributes

We write a custom `RegularExpressionAttribute` for our MVC3 application. The purpose of Customizing `RegularExpressionAttribute` is that, we want to replace a token within in a resource file message with  a keyword. E.g. “Field __ has some invalid characters”.

So we want to replace `_` token with `Address` keyword.

```
ResourceManager(_resourceManagerType.FullName, 
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyNames.TRUETRAC_RESOURCES)).GetString(_errorMessageResourceName).Replace("_","Address");
```

The of Custom attribute is as following,

```
public class CustomRegularExpressionAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    string _errorMessageResourceName;
    Type _resourceManagerType;

    public CustomRegularExpressionAttribute(string _pattern, string fieldName, string errorMessageResourceName, Type resourceManagerType)
        : base(_pattern)
    {
        _errorMessageResourceName = errorMessageResourceName;
        _resourceManagerType = resourceManagerType;

        this.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(fieldName);
    }
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string fieldName)
    {
        return //Resources.en_MessageResource.ResourceManager.GetString(fieldName);
        new ResourceManager(_resourceManagerType.FullName, System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyNames.TRUETRAC_RESOURCES)).GetString(_errorMessageResourceName).Replace("__", fieldName);    
    }
}

public class CustomRegularExpressionValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<CustomRegularExpressionAttribute>
{
    private readonly string _message;
    private readonly string _pattern;

    public CustomRegularExpressionValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, CustomRegularExpressionAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        _pattern = attribute.Pattern;
        _message = attribute.ErrorMessage;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = _message,
            ValidationType = "regex"
        };

        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("pattern", _pattern);

        return new[] { rule };
    }
}
```

Then we register this attribute in Global.aspx Application_Start event.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        // Register CustomRegularExpressionValidator
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(CustomRegularExpressionAttribute), typeof(CustomRegularExpressionValidator));

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

And applied to our models properties like that:

```
[CustomRegularExpression(RegularExpression.Alphanumeric, "Address", "CV_Address", typeof(Resources.en_MessageResource))]
    public string Address { get; set; }
```

Problem is that we are implementing localization in our Application and constructor of `CustomRegularExpressionAttribute` is calling only one time.
Like if starting culture of application is English and then we change the culture of application to Spanish, but the messages for `CustomRegularExpressionAttribute` are still displaying in English, because constructor of `CustomRegularExpressionAttribute` is calling only for one time, and it has been called for English messages.

Can any one tell why is the problem? Why the constructor of `CustomRegularExpressionAttribute` is not calling for every request??

Answer (score 0):

The method `Application_Start` is only called once, at the **start** of the **application**. Additionally, attributes are compiled, so they can be read (via reflection or metadata), but not altered, at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when initializing the ErrorMessage property in the constructor of my custom validation attribute.

My solution is to override the `IsValid` method. Just call `base.IsValid` here. This method returns null if it's valid else it will return a `ValidationResult` where you can set the `ErrorMessage` property.

```
    public class RequiredAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
{    
            public RequiredAttribute()
            {
            }

            protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
                    {
                        string displayName = validationContext.DisplayName;
                        ValidationResult result = base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
                        if (result != null)
                            result.ErrorMessage = string.Format(GetTranslatation("RequiredField"), displayName);
                        return result;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Since `IsValid` is always executed during validation it will always return the message in the current language.